# Is this a good way to acces a gameobject in a collider array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Collider2D[] isInRange = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, range,whatIsPlayer);
isInRange[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * gForce);
```

Is this a good way to acces a GameObject in a collider array ?
Also, in your opinion, should i put this chunk of code in FixedUpdate() method or Update() ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an array of Collider2D, the best way is to iterate over it. Also, `Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll()` it's pretty CPU intensive, so placing in `FixedUpdate()` should be the best case scenario.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
   Collider2D[] cols = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, range, player);

   for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++)
   {
      // Apply AddForce() to each founded Rigidbody2D
      cols[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * force);
   }
}
```

This implementation also saves you from a NullReferenceException, in case the Collider2D[] is empty (so there is no element 0).